# How to create array object and update it's value

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I come from Javascript background and I interface/implementation is new to me.

Consider I have a participant whose interface & implementation looks like this

**Participant.h file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Participant : NSObject
    @property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSString *name;
    @property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSString *id;
    @property(nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSString *gender;
+ (instancetype _Nonnull)sharedInstance;

@end
```

**Participant.m file**

```
@implementation Participant


- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setAllValueNil];
        [self initMessageEmit];
    }
    return self;
}



-(void)setAllValueNil {
    _name = nil;
    _id = nil;
    _gender = nil;
}


- (void)initMessageEmit {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(receiveNotification:)
            name:@"participantReciever"
            object:nil];
}

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
      static Participant *sharedInstance = nil;
      static dispatch_once_t OnceToken;
      dispatch_once(OnceToken, ^{
          sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
      });
      return sharedInstance;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}


- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"participantReciever"]) {
        if (notification.userInfo[@"value"] != nil) {
            if ([notification.userInfo[@"type"] isEqualToString:@"setName"]) {
            _name = notification.userInfo[@"value"]
          } 
        }
     }
```

This code is for **single Participant** but if I were to have multiple participant, How will I write the above code? Can someone please share an example? Where id being a unique key

Comment: Unclear what the question is. If you have multiple participants you would throw away your `sharedInstance` method which makes this a singleton. If you want my advice you should throw it away in any case. Even in JavaScript there is a concept of classes and instances (sort of). — I've suggested this before; why not _learn_ Objective-C instead of thrashing around?

Comment: There is no need to explicitly set the properties to `nil`; That is done for you.  As @matt said, there is no reason for this object to be a singleton, especially since you have said you want multiple instances.  Using a notification set your property is also needlessly complicated; You would normally have a reference to the object instance and simply set the property. You can use a `uuid` as a unique key, although this would be unusual for an in-memory object. You can either pass it to the initialiser or have the initialiser assign a random one.

Comment: I note that you have made your properties read-only.  This eliminates the simple property setter.  Is that really your intention, since you ask "how to update its value" in your question title?  Can you [edit] your question to explain more clearly what you want to do?

Comment: Hey @matt! Thanks for commenting. 
Certainly that's the best way to go and I will do it. The code snippet above is for a **single participant** and not **participants**.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by saying what *@matt* & *@Paulw11* suggested above would be the way to go. If you need an array of objects of this type, you should not need to make it a singleton.

Also making properties readonly in the interface and only allowing modifications through NotificationCenter is not the best idea. Say you were to modify one value on 10 instances, you would need to fire 10 notifications, handle them. This gets unnecessarily complicated for an array of instances of this type.

---

Moving on, you are adding a notification observer like this -

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver: self
    selector: @selector(receiveNotification:)
    name: @"participantReciever"
    object: nil
];
```

When you specify `object: nil`, your `selector` will be called without any instance filtering. Say you have 10 instances of this type in memory, a notification with name `"participantReciever"` is posted, (all 10 instances would receive this notification).

What you can do instead is -

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver: self
    selector: @selector(receiveNotification:)
    name: @"participantReciever"
    object: self // note this
];
```

Now you are specifying `object: self` you will receive only those notifications that affect this particular instance GIVEN you specify that `object: <object_that_you_want_to_modify>` while posting the notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName: @"participantReciever",
    object: Participant.sharedInstance, // note this
    userInfo: @{@"name": @"Test"}
];
```

Comment: Thanks Tarun, This is super helpful. 
I want to stick to the message emit pattern for now and I also do want to anyone to subscribe to these notification. 
Can you please help me out with have interface having array of objects? (participants)

Comment: When you are using above setup for multiple instances, just remember to pass correct instance in `object: <instance_you_wish_to_modify>` with `postNotificationName:` call and there's no need for any extra id checks.